# Error "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'" via tomcat7

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I have faced with strange situation.
When I run my project via intellij idea with following configuration - `clean install tomcat7:run -e` - everything processes successfully.

But when i manually copy .war file into the tomcat7 directory and start server i am getting an error in tomcat log:

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 8 in XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 33;
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no
>   declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'.

Here is my spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
....
```

I have found some solutions regarding namespaces but they don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have the `spring-context-4.1.x.RELEASE.jar` in you war `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: No, I have such library in my war WEB-INF/lib directory

Comment: @ivan_ochc Try disabling validation with an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to see if context file is parsed fine (use the method ctx#setValidating)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem.
I think, that problem was in cashed data in `target` folder.
After executing following command `mvn clean package` - problem is gone.